# WordPress categories with subcategories in a dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

I need to do a search page for WordPress where there are 10 categories for posts and each of those 10 categories have subcategories

Example:

```
FirstCat (parent)  
    Subcat1 (child)
    Subcat2 (child)
SecondCat (parent)
    Subcat1 (child)
    Subcat2 (child)
.
.
.
```

**Question:** How I can make a dropdown box for each show parent category and include children in dropbox? I think this can be some how do with by using `wp_dropdown_categories` function, but I don't know munch about Wordpress programming yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use:

```
$args = array(
  'option_none_value'  => '-1',
  'orderby'            => 'ID',
  'order'              => 'ASC',
  'show_count'         => 0,
  'hide_empty'         => 1,
  'child_of'           => 0,
  'echo'               => 0,
  'selected'           => 0,
  'hierarchical'       => 1,
  'name'               => 'cat',
  'class'              => 'postform',
  'depth'              => 0,
  'tab_index'          => 0,
  'taxonomy'           => 'category',
  'hide_if_empty'      => false,
  'value_field'      => 'term_id',
); 

 echo wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

[Reference URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).